# Reverse contents of a field within a dataframe using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, reverse

I'm using scala.

I have a dataframe with millions of rows and multiple fields.   One of the fields is a string field containing thing like this:

"Snow_KC Bingfamilies Conference_610507"

How do I reverse the contents of just this field for all the rows in the dataframe?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a quick search on the **Scaladoc**, I found this [`reverse` *function*](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@reverse(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) which does exactly that.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{functions => sqlfun}
val df1 = ...
val df2 = df1.withColumn("columnName", sqlfun.reverse($"columnName"))
```